# PhpMyadmin on Docker/MySQL on host

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install/configure phpmyadmin using docker inside Ubuntu 14.04. I started like this:

```
docker run --name myadmin -d -e PMA_HOST=localhost -e PMA_PORT=3306 -p 8282:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

When I try to login I get the following error:

```
 #2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 &quot;No such file or directory&quot;) &mdash; The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 &quot;No such file or directory&quot;)
```

The MySQL server is installed directly in Ubuntu not in docker.

Any ideas?

Comment: what `service mysql status` replies ?

Comment: Running... Mysql database is live with some sites.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use localhost in your docker container.

```
docker run --rm --name myadmin -it -e PMA_HOST=172.17.0.1 -e PMA_PORT=3306 -p 8282:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

Where 172.17.0.1 is my host ip of the docker0 bridge.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

1. Check you have your db up and running:

```
    "service mysql status" or "systemctl status mysqld"
```

(It should say active(running))

2. Run phpMyAdmin in a container:

```
    docker run --name="phpMyAdmin-local" -itd -e PMA_HOST=$(ip route show | grep docker0 | awk '{print $9}') -p 8283:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

3. Check container is up and running:

```
    docker ps -a
```

(check phpMyAdmin-local status is up)

4. Go to "localhost:8283" and check phpMyAdmin is there
5. Let your db receive external requests:

Edit file as sudo:

MariaDb:
nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

MySQL:
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

(nano is the text editor and can be changed)

and change this line:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

To this line: (note the "#")

```
# bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

(ctrl+x to exit, "y" to save it and "enter" to confirm)

6. Give permision to users/user to connect from a different location (different from localhost):

Modify users and login to mysql/mariadb cli with root privileges:

```
    mysql -uroot -p -P3306
```

(enter password after running command)

Use mysql database to edit users:

```
use mysql;
```

Give pribvileges to specific user: (can be different from root if you have other users):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Then:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and:

```
exit;
```

Restart mysql service:

```
service mysqld stop
```

```
service mysqld start
```

And now you would be able to login to phpMyAdmin  with the user and password you specify in prev. commands and mysql/mariadb would accept connections.

Answer (score 1):

For mac OS users, use host.docker.internal as the host address which docker will resolve to the host's IP address.

```
docker run --rm --name myadmin -it -e PMA_HOST=host.docker.internal -e PMA_PORT=3306 -p 8282:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and none of the previous answers worked for me. I found the solution in the [GitHub issue 271](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/issues/271#issuecomment-898884172), which maps the local socket into the docker container:

docker run --rm --name pma-socket -p 8080:80 -e PMA_SOCKET=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -v /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock phpmyadmin:latest

Answer (score -2):

**Instead of connecting through socket file try to connect using IP (127.0.0.1) and for PMA port use your machine IP which you can get through ifconfig command.**